# Delete registry key or value via a CMD script?

Tags: command-line, windows-registry

How do I edit an already-in-production `.cmd` script file, in order to have the script delete a certain registry key in the Windows registry?

Firstly, is this even possible, and secondly (if that's not possible), could I create a `.reg` file and execute that file from with the `.cmd` file?

From within the `.cmd` script, it is not working:

```
del "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\SampleKey]"
```

This method hasn't worked for me either:

```
cmd "\\networkdrive\regfiles\deleteSampleKey.reg"
```

Then from within the `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[
-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
]
```

Comment: using a .reg file, even from a network drive should work fine. If it isn't, then, I expect it is down to UAC or other security measures.

Answer (score 44):

I would recommend using the **REG** command, rather than creating and importing .reg files.

```
reg delete "HKCU\Some\Registry\Path" /f
```

or

```
reg delete "HKLM\Some\Registry\Path" /f
```

These commands can be entered directly into the batch (`.cmd`) file.

Answer (score 29):

As [described here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php) and [here by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516) under the section "Deleting Registry Keys and Values" create a `.reg` file containing the keys or values you want to remove.

## Delete a key

You can remove a registry ***key*** by placing a hyphen (minus character) **"-"** in front of the key like that:

```
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\YourSoft\MyKey]
```

## Delete a value

To remove a registry ***value***, place a hyphen (minus character) **"-"** after the = character like that:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\YourSoft\MyKey]
"MyEntry"=-
```

Comment: Indeed, it works.

Comment: Another reference is *[How to add, modify, or delete registry subkeys and values by using a .reg file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516)* (Microsoft, KB 310516).

Comment: @Peter Mortensen This is even a more official reference. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: ironically that microsoft support link currently gives "Server Error in '/app/content' Application."

Comment: @sdjuan the Microsoft Support link works again.

Answer (score 14):

I would avoid using another script as you *can* do this in a .cmd file using the [REG](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643.aspx) commands.

You can do something similar to this:

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SomeProgram"
```

If you would like to delete only specific entries then you should add a `/v "EntryName"` argument after the path to the key. E. g:

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SomeProgram" /v "EntryName"
```

Both of these will cause a warning to be issued before deleting the values. To avoid that, you should use the `/f` argument at the end.

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SomeProgram" /f
```

Comment: Thank you. The only place on the net I could find which references a sub key.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following method. This is part of a [MRU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_menus_in_Microsoft_Windows#Most_Recently_Used_menu) ripper for Windows XP, that might help. This is the text of a batch file, that is run from CMD or from a shortcut. It creates a registry file using simple echo redirections, then imports it.

```
REM *** START REGISTRY SHREDDER ***
ECHO CREATING MRU REGISTRY
ECHO .
 ECHO > "%TMP%\MRUKILL.reg" Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
ECHO >> "%TMP%\MRUKILL.reg" [-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Doc Find Spec MRU]
ECHO >> "%TMP%\MRUKILL.reg" [-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FindComputerMRU]

REM ***  IMPORT THAT REG TO WIPE OUT THEM KEYS AND VALUES ****
regedit "%TMP%\MRUKILL.reg"
```

I am not a coder, I just do some batch stuff for myself, so I often can't even read what I wrote, but I would use that as a template for doing something else.

The `echos` are redirected (`>`) to a file, with the single `>` for the first redirection, and `>>` to append to the same file. The `-` sign is used to remove a registry entry. It would probably be good to leave off the last line, and view the file it created before importing. Importing can be done silently, but I won't do that myself.

Disclaimer: Because a person can do some serious damage to the system removing registry entries, an disk image backup that can return the system when the system fails is necessary.

Proper permissions, elevations, and some entries in the registry will not just allow the user to destroy them, without setting the permissions, because of their importance.

Here is A "ask the user" part, added just for fun.

```
ECHO
 REM *** ASK the USER FIRST ***  
ECHO  DO YOU WANT TO DELETE REGISTRY MRUS?
SET /P Choice2=type "Y" to Mangle your registry, - -
ECHO . 
IF /I "%Choice2%"=="Y" GOTO SHREDD
ECHO OK WELL THEN I WON'T
ECHO By By 
   REM *** USER DECIDED AGAINST IT ***
ECHO .
PAUSE
GOTO FINISH
```

Comment: on Vista + this method will invoke UAC. and user will have to accept or decline this action. Running the script as Admin will bypass that though

Comment: you should not use %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp, but %TMP%. the former works only on english systems

Comment: @kinokijuf Feexed, looks much nicer that way too.  It was probably set like that to keep it on system disk for me, because I have sent Temps to ramdisk or to data disks at times.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Windows 7 and this is what I got through CMD:

```
Fri 08/08/2014  8:13:51.72 | C:\Users\MrCMD
>reg.exe delete /?

REG DELETE KeyName [/v ValueName | /ve | /va] [/f]

  KeyName    [\\Machine\]FullKey
    Machine  Name of remote machine - omitting defaults to the current machine.
             Only HKLM and HKU are available on remote machines.
    FullKey  ROOTKEY\SubKey
    ROOTKEY  [ HKLM | HKCU | HKCR | HKU | HKCC ]
    SubKey   The full name of a registry key under the selected ROOTKEY.

  ValueName  The value name, under the selected Key, to delete.
             When omitted, all subkeys and values under the Key are deleted.

  /ve        delete the value of empty value name (Default).

  /va        delete all values under this key.

  /f         Forces the deletion without prompt.

Examples:

  REG DELETE HKLM\Software\MyCo\MyApp\Timeout
    Deletes the registry key Timeout and its all subkeys and values

  REG DELETE \\ZODIAC\HKLM\Software\MyCo /v MTU
    Deletes the registry value MTU under MyCo on ZODIAC
```

Or, I think we can DELETE some keys or MODIFY some values by this algorithm:

1. Export registry location of keys/values we want to delete/modify into a file (File01.reg).
2. Edit/modify appropriate key/value and save to new file (File02.reg).
3. Import that modified file (File02.reg) into Windows Registry.

Reference to EXPORT registry.

```
Fri 08/08/2014  8:24:53.19 | C:\Users\mardir01
>reg.exe export /?

REG EXPORT KeyName FileName [/y]

  Keyname    ROOTKEY[\SubKey] (local machine only).
    ROOTKEY  [ HKLM | HKCU | HKCR | HKU | HKCC ]
    SubKey   The full name of a registry key under the selected ROOTKEY.

  FileName   The name of the disk file to export.

  /y       Force overwriting the existing file without prompt.

Examples:

  REG EXPORT HKLM\Software\MyCo\MyApp File01.reg
    Exports all subkeys and values of the key MyApp to the file File01.reg
```

Reference to IMPORT registry.

```
>reg.exe import /?

REG IMPORT FileName

  FileName  The name of the disk file to import (local machine only).

Examples:

  REG IMPORT File02.reg
    Imports registry entries from the file File02.reg
```

Brighter ideas for improvement are welcome. :) :) :)